# Are struct names pointers to first element?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I found a few similar questions but none of them helped much. Are struct names pointers to the first element of the struct, similar to an array?

```
struct example {
    int foo;
    int bar;
};

struct example e;
e.foo = 5;
e.bar = 10;
printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", e, e.foo, e.bar, &e, &e.foo, &e.bar);
```

Output:

```
5
5
10
2033501712
2033501712
2033501716
```

All of the answers to the other questions said "no", but this output confuses me. All help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The address of a `struct` is indeed the address of the first element, though you'll need to know the type of the element in order to safely cast it.

> (C17 §6.7.2.1.15: "A pointer to a structure object, suitably
>   converted, points to its initial member ... and vice versa. There may
>   be unnamed padding within as structure object, but not at its
>   beginning.")

While it's kind of ugly, numerous pieces of production software rely on this. QNX, for example, uses this kind of behavior in open control block (OCB) logic when writing resource managers. Gtk also something similar.

Your current implementation is dangerous though. If you must rely on this behavior, do it like so, and don't attempt to pass a pointer-to-struct as an argument to `printf()`, as you're intentionally breaking a feature of a language with minimal type-safety.

```
struct example {
    int foo;
    int bar;
};

struct example myStruct = { 1, 2 };
int* pFoo = (int*)&myStruct;
printf("%d", *pFoo);
```

Finally, this only holds for the first element. Subsequent elements may not be situation where you expect them to be, [namely due to `struct` packing and padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-structure-packing).

Comment: You should change the term 'point to' in your first sentence, otherwise a certain someone might downvote your answer into oblivion.

Comment: Interesting how that might apply to a member you can't have a pointer to.  (A bitfield, for example)

Answer (score 4):

`struct` names aren't pointers to anything. You are invoking *undefined behaviour* by passing a `struct` to `printf` with an incompatible format specifier `%d`. It may seem to "work" because the first member of the struct has the same address as the `struct` itself.

Comment: I don't really see how it is "working" at all, the size of the struct being a different size to int "should" lead to all the other output being garbled

Comment: @M.M UB? Maybe the parameters are read backwards on OP's platform.