# Is it safe to cast an array to a struct with one array as member?

Tags: c, arrays, casting, java-native-interface

In the following setup

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char data[64];
} mystruct;

int myfunc(mystruct* arg); // fills arg with data
```

is it **safe** to call `myfunc` with a pointer to a 64 byte array? E.g.

```
unsigned char buffer[64];
myfunc((mystruct*) buffer)
```

In my concrete application I am using a JNI direct ByteBuffer which should be filled from `myfunc`.

```
unsigned char* dbbuffer = (unsigned char*) (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, jbuffer);
```

If the cast is not safe, I would have to create a `mystruct`, call `myfunc` and then `memcopy` to `dbbuffer`, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Strict aliasing rule - that won't leave it.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/7312630/4386427

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597425/are-struct-names-pointers-to-first-element

Comment: So, technically it works, but I must not use it due to the strict aliasing rule!?

Comment: Strict aliasing doesn't apply since the struct contains a type which is compatible with the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically it works and you can use it. As pointed in comments the relevant part of the ANSI standard is:

6.7.2.1: Structure and union specifiers

> ... A pointer to a
>   structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
>   bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed
>   padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

The strict aliasing does not matter in this case. 
Strict aliasing rule specifies in which circumstances a value of some type can be changed by changing a value of another type. The main interest of this rule are scalar types like `int` and `float`. In your particular case it is evident that by changing a member of a struct (`unsigned char []`) you change the whole structure and vice versa.

This case is covered by the 5th subcase of the strict aliasing rule. I quote the whole part for the sake of completeness:

6.5 Expressions, p.7

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
>   the following types (The intent of this list is to specify those circumstances in which an object may or may not be aliased):
>
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the
>   object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the
>   effective type of the object,
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its
>   members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
>
> — a character type

where the definition of *aggegate types* is in:

6.2.5 Types, p.21

> Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called scalar types. Array and
>   structure types are collectively called aggregate types.

Comment: Note that it slips through strict aliasing just because the struct contains the exact type `unsigned char [64]`, same type as the effective type of the original array. Had the original array been of a different size than the one in the struct, I believe this would be a strict aliasing violation.

Comment: In C stanadard gibberish: the struct is an aggregate that includes one of the aforemntioned types, namely a type compatible with the effective type of the object. Two arrays are compatible if they have both the same type specifier and same size.

Comment: @Lundin Sure. However, arrays decay to pointers  in majority of circumstance. An example where array members can't be aliased will look rather artificially.

Comment: Array decay has nothing to do with declared types. An example where array members can't be aliased would simply be `unsigned char buffer[63]; myfunc((mystruct*) buffer)`. Since `unsigned char[63]` and `unsigned char[64]` are not compatible types. (C11 6.2.7 which for the case of arrays points at 6.7.6.2/6)

Comment: My point is that you can not assign the whole array to another array (only as part of a larger aggregate type). In a real code any assignment between `char[63]` and `char[64]` will go through altering individual `char`s.

Comment: Given `typedef struct { unsigned char data[64]; } mystruct;` and `typedef struct { unsigned char data[64]; } mystruct64;`, you can assign the whole arrays through `mystruct ms; mystruct64 ms64; ... ms = *(mystruct*)&ms64;`. This is perfectly valid and well-defined code.